# Can't detect gramex.yaml file when using Conda for Gramex

Tags: installation, gramex

I'm trying to run gramex on the Conda prompt, but it's throwing an error--
No gramex.yaml. See https://learn.gramener.com/guide/

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

In the same directory where you're running Gramex, you can create a new `gramex.yaml` file (even an empty one is fine). Then re-run Gramex. You should see a list of files.

Another option is to create a new directory and run `gramex init`. Then run `gramex`, like this:

```sh
mkdir projectname
cd projectname
gramex init
gramex
```

This is explained at https://gramener.com/gramex/guide/install/#run-a-gramex-app